# Loss of precision with very small numbers in Python arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays in float64 type and when I assign the value of the first to the second it rounds the value. The following simple code illustrates the problem and excludes the possibility of just a mere number representation thing. (I've schematized a fragment of my code to be more readable, but it is in essence the same thing)

```
X = zeros((2,2))
Y = zeros((2,2))
Z = X            #a shorter way of making a new matrix, equal to X...
X[0,0] = Y[0,0]
Z[0,0]=0
print Y[0,0]
print X[0,0]
print type(Y[0,0])
print type(X[0,0])
if X[0,0]==Y[0,0]:
   print'they are equal'
else:
   print'they are NOT equal'
```

I ran this little snippet of code for all coefficients and all the outputs are similar to this:

```
1.90897e-14
0
<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
they are NOT equal
```

It seems to me that the X array is of another type, but it's created in the same way, with the zeros() function with the standard type (float64)

Edit: The arrays are initialized with

```
X = zeros((2,2), dtype=float64)
Y = zeros((2,2), dtype=float64)
```

Also included an additional useful print in the example above.

Edit: added the problematic lines, after I found the problem

Comment: Could you also include the snippet where you create `X` and `Y`?

Comment: Could you also include the result of `print type(X), type(Y)`?

Comment: Sure:
X = zeros((2,2), dtype=float64)
Y = zeros((2,2), dtype=float64)

Comment: Both type(X) and type(Y) are not very helpful ("<type 'numpy.ndarray'>").
But type(X[0,0]) and type(Y[0,0]) both return "<type 'numpy.float64'>"
(this is important, I'm going to update the question with this info)

Comment: @Diego: when do you call "type(X[0,0])"?  At time of construction or right before the above snippet?  It's the latter I'm interested in-- I think something happens to X en route.

Comment: Okay, now I'm annoyed. :-| That should not have happened if my pet theory were correct.  Could you post the absolute smallest case, from start to finish, that reproduces it, as well as your python/numpy version numbers?

Comment: @Diego.  When I run this `print zeros((2,2), dtype=float64)[0,0]` I get `0.0`.  Your code suggests you just get `0`.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm trying to write a small code that reproduces this behavior. So far everything works as expected! My original code is rather big so it might take a while for me to spot where the problem is happening and reproduce it in a small code :|

Comment: @Diego: What does `X.dtype` and `Y.dtype` give you?

Comment: @Diego: while we're at it, what architecture are you on, and what compiler?

Comment: claiming "...a fragment of my code to be more readable, but it is in essence the same thing" means we have to believe that first...

Comment: All right, I have solved the problem! While trying to reproduce the clean the code enough to present here I removed a supposedly non important line.. and it worked. 
I'm +1 all answers, as you were very helpful and the way the problem is stated there it can't be solved.

Comment: What is the best way to proceed here, as to make this question useful for future readers? should I add this important line and mark it as the problem or add the line and the answer separately?

Comment: @Diego: it's fine to submit an answer to your own question and accept it.  But please do explain in detail what happened, because I'm very surprised that anything would report its type as numpy.float64 but print as 0 instead of 0.0.

Comment: There! you can satisfy your curiosity now :) It's a pretty newbie mistake probably..

Comment: I'm going to let someone else respond because I don't really understand why Z=X behaves like that. I used thinking it would create a new matrix equal to X, but instead it seems to just give X a new name! So assigning a value to Z changes the value of X.. does that make sense?

Comment: Oh yeah, it easily solved by using Z = X.copy() instead

Comment: @Diego: In Python, `a = some_expression` is **NOT** an assignment. It is a binding of the name `a` to whatever object is produced by evaluating the expression. If that object is mutable, mutating `a` mutates that object. `Z = X` is not giving X a new name. X is not an object, it is a name. `Z = X` is giving an additional name (Z) to the object to which X refers.

Comment: Frustrating to find this out this way. Especially given the nature of my programming needs.. it's hard enough to understand the physics behind my 'intended' simulations, knowing this kind of peculiarity may be affecting my results is really annoying!

Any further advice would be appreciated :)

Comment: Don't be frustrated. Don't blame your tools. Just learn the language.

Answer (score 3):

Are you *absolutely certain* that X is a float64 array?  If it were, I'd expect X[0,0] to be 0.0, but you see 0 instead, which looks to me like an integer..

```
>>> Xf = arange(10,dtype=float64)
>>> Xi = arange(10)
>>> Xf[0]
0.0
>>> Xi[0]
0
>>> Yf = Xf*0.0
>>> Yf[0]
0.0
>>> 
>>> Yf[0] = 1.90897e-14
>>> Yf[0]
1.9089700000000001e-14
>>> Xf[0] = Yf[0]
>>> Xf[0]
1.9089700000000001e-14
>>> Xi[0] = Yf[0]
>>> Xi[0]
0
```

Comment: I think you forgot the Q.E.D.

Comment: The zeros function, when passed only the shape, assumes a float64 type.. I'm going to explicitly define them as float64 and report back here :)

Comment: @Diego: I was thinking more along the lines that the X you have isn't the one you think you have..