# to_panel fills nonexistent values with (seemingly) huge random numbers

Tags: python, pandas

(The following happens in both 0.7.3 and 0.8-dev versions)

When converting a properly multi-indexed DataFrame to a Panel using the axis "cell" of the Panel will have the huge random numbers in every Item of the `to_panels()` method, resulting "cells" that did not exist in the DataFrame are now populated with random, giant numbers (sometimes negative). For example: if the DataFrame is indexed on width and length with values from 1 to 5 for both, but there is no 2,3 entry in the DataFrame, the resulting 2,3 major-axis/minor-Panel.

Is this a bug? Or is there something we can do to prevent this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the number?  Is it possible that these are [*precision error zeros*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7521120/2087463)?